# Javascript managing multiple window.open

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build a functionality that need to load about 200 new windows to the user, but close them when they are done loading, or after lets say, 10 seconds.

However I know that opening that many pages at the same time is actually impossible, as it would crash the client's browser. So what I am trying to do is manage the new window.opens so as it loads only five by five. and once one page has been closed it loads another from the queue.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    var loadingQueue = localStorage.loadingQueue ? JSON.parse(localStorage.loadingQueue) : [];
    var timeToLoad = 10000;

    var windowArray = [];
    var self = this;

    var timedLoading = function () {
      if (loadingQueue.length > 0 && windowArray.length < 6) {
        loadingQueue = localStorage.loadingQueue ? JSON.parse(localStorage.loadingQueue) : [];
        var url = loadingQueue.pop();

        localStorage.setItem('loadingQueue', JSON.stringify(loadingQueue));
        self.updateLength();

        var newWindow = window.open(url, '_blank');
        windowArray.push(newWindow);

        setTimeout(function () {
          var windowIndex = windowArray.indexOf(newWindow);
          var curWindow = windowArray.splice(windowIndex, 1);
          curWindow.close();
        }, timeToLoad);

        setTimeout(timedLoading, 1500);
      }
    };

    timedLoading();
```

however the pages aren't closing. I tested with only one page and it closed just fine, after the set amount of time. Why am I failing to do the same with many windows?

Any hint is much appreciated. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. As Array.splice() returns an array, I needed to specify which index I was working on.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    var windowIndex = windowArray.indexOf(newWindow);
    var curWindow = windowArray.splice(windowIndex, 1);
    curWindow[0].close();
}, timeToLoad);
```

this worked.